# Criar janela modal

Tags: react-native

Estou começando um app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar
} from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class ouvidoria extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.geral}>

        <StatusBar 
          //hidden
          backgroundColor='#005288'
        />

        <View style={styles.botao}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => { Actions.formaanonima(); }}
            containerStyle={{ padding:10, 
                              height:50,
                              width:300,
                              overflow:'hidden', 
                              //borderRadius:4, 
                              justifyContent: 'center',
                              alignItems: 'center',
                              backgroundColor: '#FFB504',
                              elevation: 10,
                              }}
            style={{fontSize: 24, 
                    color: '#000'
                    }}>
            Cadastrar Manifestação
          </Button>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  geral: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#005288',
  },
  botao: {

  }
});
```

Procurei e não consegui encontrar como fazer para abrir janelas.

Gostaria que quando o usuário apertasse no botão abrisse uma janela perguntando se este já possui cadastro ou não, apenas com os botões de sim e não para decidir qual rota seguir.

Porém não encontrei este tipo de função no React-native nem em material de terceiros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um exemplo simples

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
)
```

Voce pode ver mais [aqui](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html)

Comment: Sabe se é possível editar a janela de alert?

Comment: O Alert não tem style configurável, pois ele usa o alert nativo de cada plataforma. Você pode usar o [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) do próprio React Native se quiser customizar a janela.